# is_logged_in check on every page

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using CodeIgniter. I have a controller named `abc` and i has functions named `index`,`a`,`b`and`c`.

```
www.example.com/abc/
```

I want that user can only access the area he is logged in.

```
www.example.com/abc/                    //if loggged in else back to homepage
```

or

```
 www.example.com/abc/a/                    //if loggged in else back to homepage
```

Now to check login. I use:

`if($this->auth->is_logged_in()) { .. } else { redirect('/'); }`

on every function individually.

**Is there any other way to do so ??**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do this by overriding the constructor and call your function in it.

```
<?php
class Blog extends CI_Controller {

       public function __construct()
       {
            parent::__construct();
            // check login
       }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

For a particular controller you can put  your if check in the `constructor` of the controller so that when  any method of the controller is called it will pass through your if check

```
class Abc extends CI_Controller {

       public function __construct()
       {
            parent::__construct();
            //your if goes here
       }
}
```

And if you want to check the user is logged in or not in the whole application you can use the constructor method `__construct()` of `CI_Controller` so it will be validated when user access any of the controllers within your application

```
class CI_Controller {

    private static $instance;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
           //your if goes here

    }

 }
```